# Create MVC 3 ASPXAUTH cookie from MVC 5.1 application - Single Sign on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, cryptography

I have 2 seperate websites, the main one running .NET 4.5 MVC 5.1 the other on a subdomain running .NET 4.0 MVC3.

I want to do single sign-in so when the user logs into the main site I need to set a cookie for the subdomain to read as if the user is logged in there too. The problem is calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` with the same paramters from the 2 application results in a different cookie. I need to create an MVC 3 ASPXAUTH cookie **from the MVC 5.1 application**

Simply using the MVC 5.1 generated cookie doesn't log the user into the MVC 3 application. 
I've set the machine key to the same for both application but the one generated by MVC3 is about 50 characters longer than the one I set (total is something like 150+ characters).

Actually here's the 2 cookies:

```
using System.Web.Security.Cryptography;
byte[] binaryMVC3Cookie = CryptoUtil.HexToBinary("0B406403C8FB8DE06FBF43291C48BED31C41FC2DCDFB81541A65A2B842E63B609FA6D146F3CF68968240ED5D5EF75A2FEC2C0D4B4FF99CD4DAF974D264A08D794BBF75EB6C4F40F08F9A6A97B1A4E130B9FC9CC9E5C55E93D06D9A9D56427110637874DA4059D18D0D4929DE04360DF72E13DB09");
byte[] binaryMVC5Cookie = CryptoUtil.HexToBinary("6D0C1B88CC6FB663B59FBAEC4BBDF02751C8EC70F2988BBC175F750AF7CE32412BFB2C8F79D24B0E6E832A51CCF479D7492A49D808A8C101FAB050E410D8F561BD7944694DF7DD74F09CF348D1BDD7E2BC0D9709");
```

`FormsAuthentication.Decrypt()` works fine on the MVC5 cookie (of course since it was generated there) but it throws a Cryptography exception for the MVC 3 cookie. So I decompiled the assembly and executed lines of interest in the Immediate Window to find that the exception is throw internally from the following line:

```
ICryptoService cryptoService = AspNetCryptoServiceProvider.Instance.GetCryptoService(Purpose.FormsAuthentication_Ticket, CryptoServiceOptions.None);
byte[] numArray = cryptoService.Unprotect(binaryMVC3Cookie); //Here exception
```

I'm going to need to recreate that MVC 3 cookie from my MVC 5.1 app. If anyone has any ideas please do tell!

**EDIT**: I just had an epiphany how to circumvent all hackery. I'll just make a WebClient call to the MVC 3 app and get the correct cookie value. =O (Note making a WebClient call to the login method on the MVC3 application and having it call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie did NOT work. I had to actually send the cookie value over and set it as a subdomain cookie in the main app

Comment: have you tried FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie?

Comment: I updated with some more info. I just turned Forms module back on and used SetAuthCookie to test, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: Do you have identical machine keys set in the `web.config` of the two sites?

Comment: Does that coincide with them being on the same machine? If so yes I'm developing the solutions side by side

Comment: No, the applications can exist on the same machine, but they will use uniquely generated keys unless you specify one in the web.config. Here's some more detail from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and also a key generator: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Thanks Brent. Just tried setting both apps to have same machineKey. I was so sure this would work but it didn't. The call to FormAuthentication.SetAuthCookie from the subdomain still generates a longer, working cookie while the shorter from the main site fails to log the user into the subdomain

Comment: Thought that would be it to. Next thought, try setting `domain="site.com"` in the `<forms>` element.

Comment: Still doesnt. In fact the resulting cookie is the same (".site.com"). I also tried "sub.site.com" in that case it doesnt generate the cookie at all

Comment: Last shot, after this I'm out of ideas, try explicitly setting the domain in code `var authcookie = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(UserName, False); authcookie.Domain = "site.com";`

Comment: I tried this before (may be visible in my edits thats I removed). Ill try again tom but I doubt it. Thanks though Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We improved the entire cryptographic stack in ASP.NET 4.5.  The end result is that the forms authentication ticket format is different for your MVC 3 (.NET 4.0) application vs. your MVC 5.1 (.NET 4.5) application.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx for lots more info on this.  Here's an excerpt from that document detailing how to achieve backward compatibility so that you can share cookies between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 applications:

> If you are writing an application targeting ASP.NET 4.5 (you have set
>   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />) and you need to share
>   tickets with applications running earlier versions of ASP.NET, you
>   must set the following in the 4.5 project's Web.config:
>
> ```
> <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
> ```

Answer (score 1):

We have multiple web apps on the same server and they all share the same login as well.
We set a fixed **generated** **machine.key** in the machine.config so that all apps share it

this works fine for us. I haven't tried your specific situation with a mix of claim and form authentication, but maybe you could give it a try.

see [How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) it's old but still applies.

Comment: Peter what do you mean by "machine.key" and "machine.config". I set the machine key in web.config under `<system.web><machineKey .../>` I'm sure this is what you mean but just making sure.

Comment: I changed the entire question with some new details emerging. Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my ephiphany edit in the question worked successfully to accomplish the real end goal which was single-sign on across MVC5 and MVC3. What I did was make an Http request using `WebClient` class. In MVC3 I used FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie and send the cookie.Value over to the MVC 5 application where I set it as a subdomain cookie:

```
  HttpCookie forumAuthCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", response.CookieValue);
  forumAuthCookie.Domain = ".site.com";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(forumAuthCookie);
```